# Binding value to textbox inside of gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, binding, textbox

I have problems with binding a value of a field inside a gridview to a textbox which is inside the gridview as well. I'm intending to do this for editing the table.

I tried to do this with eval and bind, but the textbox won't show the values and I have absolutely no clue why.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvBS" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" SkinID="gvWithoutWidth">
         <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" EditImageUrl="~/Images/GridView/gv_edit.png" ButtonType="Image" 
                CancelImageUrl="~/Images/GridView/gv_cancel.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/GridView/gv_update.png"/>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sollmonat" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbSollMonat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SollMonat") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSollMonat" ValidationGroup="Update" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="tbSollMonat" ErrorMessage="Bitte Sollmonat (dd.mm.yyyy) angeben"
                        SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revSollMonat" ValidationGroup="Update" runat="server"
                        ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ControlToValidate="tbSollMonat">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("SollMonat")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The thing is that it works fine inside the ItemTemplate, but doesn't inside the EditItemTemplate-element. Really no clue what the problem is.

Code behind:

```
Sub gvBS_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gvBS.RowEditing
        gvBS.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    End Sub

    Sub gvBS_RowCancelingEdit() Handles gvBS.RowCancelingEdit
        Me.gvBS.EditIndex = -1
        gvBS_DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Does the GridView to edit-mode when the user clicks on the link?

Comment: Yes, although I need to click on the edit-img/button twice. The textboxes are staying empty, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the `GridView` enters never edit-mode since you aren't handling the `RowEditing` event or you didn't `DataBind` it after you've set `gvBS.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;`.

```
<asp:GridView 
    OnRowEditing="gvBS_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvBS_RowCancelingEdit"
    ID="gvBS" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" SkinID="gvWithoutWidth">
```

codebehind (`BindGrid` is the method which databinds your grid):

```
protected void gvBS_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvBS.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();
}

protected void gvBS_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gvBS.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGrid();
}
```

You should also remember to databind it only on the first load, not on consecutive postbacks when `ViewState` is enabled(default). Therefore you can check the page's `IsPostBack` property:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my last edit. I did make those methods, but well .. doesn't work. :)

Comment: @user854699: I have tested your grid with a custom DataSource(a manually filled `DataTable`)... it works as expected. You haven't databound your GridView in RowEditing. See my code.

Comment: Ohhhh I found the error. I didn't call the databind method inside the rowedit-event. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Bind instead of Eval in EditItemTemplate  like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvBS" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" SkinID="gvWithoutWidth">
     <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" EditImageUrl="~/Images/GridView/gv_edit.png" ButtonType="Image" 
            CancelImageUrl="~/Images/GridView/gv_cancel.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/GridView/gv_update.png"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sollmonat" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbSollMonat" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SollMonat") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSollMonat" ValidationGroup="Update" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="tbSollMonat" ErrorMessage="Bitte Sollmonat (dd.mm.yyyy) angeben"
                    SetFocusOnError="true">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revSollMonat" ValidationGroup="Update" runat="server"
                    ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ControlToValidate="tbSollMonat">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("SollMonat")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
```